# Automatically select next column after valid input (DataGridView with custom column)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have two datagridview columns; startdate and enddate using the custom MaskedTextBox column type described in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox

Now, I want to automatically move editing focus to the next cell on the same row when the user has entered a valid date in the column.

The way this MaskedTextBox column works is that in the *OnTextChanged()* event 
I try to convert the .Text value to a DateTime, and if that happens without exceptions I assign that DateTime value to the DataGridView.CurrentCell.Value.

Then I try to move to the next cell using the *DataGridView.CellValueChanged* event like this:

```
    private void myDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 || e.RowIndex == -1)
            return;

        //Move to next cell on the same row
        if (myDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ValueType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
        {
            try
            {
                myDataGridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                int NewColIndex = myDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1;
                if (NewColIndex > -1 && NewColIndex < myDataGridView.Columns.Count)
                    myDataGridView.CurrentCell = myDataGridView[NewColIndex, myDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
            }
            catch
            {

            }
       }
    }
```

The editing focus DO get changed to the next column/cell, BUT I get a NullReference exception when I start typing in the second column/cell, originating from the *PositionEditingControl()* method in the *DataGridViewMaskedTextCell* class.

Can anyone please tell me why that happens?

Is there a "better" way to move to the next cell than setting .CurrentCell?

---

EDIT:
It seems this problem is related to the fact that the second column also uses this custom editcontrol. Tried the same thing with a regular TextBoxColumn as the second column and that works great. There is something with the way that the second column is initializing its editing control I guess?

Comment: What about send tab key?

Comment: Sending tab key = same result

Answer (score 0):

From an ergonomy point of view, I recommend you to wait user press the 'Enter' Key prior validating the content of the cell. You should use the `CellEndEdit` event handler to catch it, instead of the `CellValueChanged`

Then, if your validation is successful (format is a DateTime), you could use the `DataGridView::SelectNextControl()` method.
As stated in this post: [DataGridView SelectNextControl](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fe4306c2-1cdf-4e1c-a94c-b3fd1e6ea58f/datagridview-selectnextcontrol)
don't forget to call `DetatchEditingControl` method of the `CurrentCell`

Comment: I cannot use Enter key like that. Enter key should result in jump to next row.

I Tried using DataGridView.SelectNextControl() in a bunch of different events - didn't work.